# spark parse json field and match to different case class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some json like below, when I loaded this json some fields is string of json,

How to parse this json using spark scala  and look for the key words I am looking for in that json

```
{"main":"{\"payload\": { \"mode\": [\"Node\"], \"currentSatate\": \"Ready\", \"Previousstate\": \"slow\", \"trigger\": [\"11\", \"12\"], \"AllStates\": [\"Ready\", \"slow\", \"fast\", \"new\"],\"UnusedStates\": [\"slow\", \"new\"],\"Percentage\": \"70\",\"trigger\": [\"11\"]}"}

{"main":"{\"payload\": {\"trigger\": [\"11\", \"22\"],\"mode\": [\"None\"],\"cangeState\": \"Open\"}}"}

{"main":"{\"payload\": { \"trigger\": [\"23\", \"45\"], \"mode\": [\"Edge\"], \"node.postions\": [\"12\", \"23\", \"45\", \"67\"], \"node.names\": [\"aa\", \"bb\", \"cc\", \"dd\"]}}" }
```

This is how its looking after loading in to data frame

```
val df = spark.read.json("<pathtojson")
df.show(false)

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|main                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"payload": { "mode": ["Node"], "currentSatate": "Ready", "Previousstate": "slow", "trigger": ["11", "12"], "AllStates": ["Ready", "slow", "fast", "new"],"UnusedStates": ["slow", "new"],"Percentage": "70","trigger": ["11"]}|
|{"payload": {"trigger": ["11", "22"],"mode": ["None"],"cangeState": "Open"}}                                                                                                                                                   |
|{"payload": { "trigger": ["23", "45"], "mode": ["Edge"], "node.postions": ["12", "23", "45", "67"], "node.names": ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"]}}                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Since my json filed is different for all the 3 json strings , is there a way to match define 3 case class and match

I know only matching to one class

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
val parsedJson = mapper.readValue[classname](jsonstring)
```

is there a way to create a multiple matching case class and match to any particular class ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using Spark SQL, the first thing you have to do is to turn it into a dataset, and then use the spark's methods to deal with them. Don't use Json, all over the place (e.g., like in Play). The first task is to turn it into a dataset.

You could turn the serialize a Json into a case class:

```
val jsonFilePath: String = "/whatever/data.json" 
val myDataSet = sparkSession.read.json(jsonFilePath).as[StudentRecord]
```

Then here you have the dataset for `StudentRecord`. So, you can now use the spark's `groupBy` method to get the data of the column you want from the dataset:

```
myDataSet.groupBy("whateverTable.whateverColumn").max() //could be min(), count(), etc...
```

**Extra Note**: Your Json, should "cleaned up" a little. For example, if it is within your program you can use the multi line way of declaring your Json, and then you don't need to use escape character all over the place:

```
val myJson: String =
  """
    {
    }
  """.stripMargin
```

If it is in the file, then the Json you wrote is not correct. So first, make sure you have a syntactically correct Json to work on.

Comment: yes,  the problem is one of field which is surrounded with " " as read as string which is in json, I need to further parse  that to extrat the value, as in my case you can check  "main" is the column which string and its value is json string

Comment: @user3607698 I updated the answer. I think first you need to check your Json for syntactical errors.

Comment: there was one typo while copying the json, now I have posted a proper one, also the how it looks after loading in to dataframe